# Rspec tests for administrative 'delete' links fail. Michael Hartl's ROR 3.2 Tutorial - Chapter 9.4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael's ROR tutorial and creating user authentication system. There is an admin privilige, which allows users to delete other users. Special 'delete' links appear on the users listing page when logged in as a priviliged admin user.
My App works fine but rspec tests are failing for a reason unknown to me.

I've separated the tests to another file `spec/requests/sat_spec.rb` and I am trying to use pry gem to debug it, but no success so far.

```
describe "delete links" do
  describe "as admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    before do
      sign_in admin
      visit users_path
      binding.pry          
    end
  it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }

  it "should be able to delete another user" do
    expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
  end    
end
```

Test Failures:

```
1) separated admin tests delete links as admin user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
   expected link "delete" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/sat_spec.rb:25:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) separated admin tests delete links as admin user should be able to delete another user
 Failure/Error: expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   no link with title, id or text 'delete' found
 # (eval):2:in `click_link'
 # ./spec/requests/sat_spec.rb:28:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/sat_spec.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What might by the problem here or **more importantly how to debug it?**

You can fork my code here https://github.com/tomek-rusilko/miniatury_katalog_2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You expect your `/users` page to contain the list of users with 'delete' link next to them. But you didn't fill your TEST db with simple users. It just contains one user, the admin. But according to your `users/_user.html.erb` this type of users doesn't have 'delete' link. So, add at least one user creation statement and try again.

Comment: Jeeez that was so obvious! I feel stupid :D Thanks a lot. Putting simple `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` before solved the problem. There is another thing that popped-up: why `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` works but `let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }` does not ?

Comment: `let` is evaluated lazily: its block won't be called until you use `user` "variable". Use `let!` (with the exclamation mark) instead if you want your block to be called immediately. But I would recommend you to put your `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` in `before` block.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did: `before(:all) { 5.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }; after(:all)  { User.delete_all }`. Again - Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
```

Which is fine, since you've got (in spec/factories.rb)

```
factory :admin do
  admin true
end
```

But meanwhile, in models/user.rb:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

My bet is that factory girl is using mass-assignment to set :admin => true, which is then being dropped by attr_accessible.

But more importantly, how do you debug it? By asking "what is happening?" and "what do I expect to be happening?" and variations thereon until you find that the answers to both questions meet in the middle. In this case, the questions I'd start with are: what is it that causes the link to display? Is that true of the model that I set up in the spec? Is the spec hitting the pages I expect it to? Is the model acting the same way when I hit the page with the browser as it is in the spec?

But all of those are just variations of "what is happening?" and "What do I expect to be happening?"

Comment: I don't exactly know how but FactoryGirls deals with it and admin attribute is set correctly. That's another interesting question. Anyways this was not the case (see above) but thanks for help and  for the sound advice - I am writing down these debugging questions and pinning it on my wall :)

Comment: Ok, it is by design that factories bypass attr_accessible